# Zoom in, Zoom out functionality in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

> Blockquote

Hi All, Please is it possible to add a Zoom in, Zoom out functionality to this code? I'm very fresh to html. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div class="sl-block" data-block-type="text" style="width: 413px; left: 29px; top: 84px; height: auto;" data-block-id="a3e059aa2efde6bb395d96de758538ef">
    <div class="sl-block-content" data-placeholder-tag="h2" data-placeholder-text="Title Text" style="text-align: left; z-index: 11;">
        <h2>
            <span style="font-size:0.7em">Career Center Floor</span>&nbsp;
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sl-block" data-block-type="text" style="width: 413px; left: 29px; top: 231px; height: auto;" data-block-id="9d9bce75d195e9e223f5d8542e6441da">
    <div class="sl-block-content" data-placeholder-tag="p" data-placeholder-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec metus justo. Aliquam erat volutpat." style="z-index: 13; text-align: left;">
        <ol>
            <li class="">
                <span style="font-size:0.9em">Clients first come in contact with career coaches when they walk into the Career Center. ​​</span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span style="font-size:0.9em">If they would love to use the computer, we confirm their information and provide them with their login credentials. </span>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sl-block" data-block-type="image" style="width: 492px; height: 277px; left: 466px; top: 84px;" data-block-id="a7d2425befcc101a308007e77988f4af">
    <div class="sl-block-style" style="z-index: 12; transform: rotate(180deg);">
        <div class="sl-block-content" style="z-index: 12; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
            <img style="" data-natural-width="2400" data-natural-height="1350" data-lazy-loaded="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-p.slid.es/uploads/762662/images/4156874/20170915_130043.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sl-block" data-block-type="text" data-block-id="a67966971a44247acc6d3c39c8e58444" style="height: auto; min-width: 30px; min-height: 30px; width: 600px; left: -134px; top: 35px;">
    <div class="sl-block-content" data-placeholder-tag="p" data-placeholder-text="Text" style="z-index: 14;">
        <p>Station # 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sl-block" data-block-type="image" data-block-id="a4223a242dc9a0bf9f41eca2258369d3" style="min-width: 30px; min-height: 30px; width: 486px; height: 322px; left: 466px; top: 360px;">
    <div class="sl-block-content" style="z-index: 15;">
        <img data-natural-width="584" data-natural-height="387" style="" data-lazy-loaded="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-p.slid.es/uploads/762662/images/4156885/f2c375d99f7def3cdccbec0cc2537cb1.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Probably, but you have to explain more what you want. How do you see this working for a user?

Comment: What do you expect the functionality to be like ? How does the user zoom-in/out ? Does the user press a button on your page ? Does the user press a key on the keyboard ?

Comment: StackOverflow works best if questions are understandable! Please add the following details to your question: (1) what do you want zoom? (2) how should the zoom work and (3) how would you implement it? Please do some reasearch and edit and clarify your question.

Comment: I'm sorry guy see details.  (1) what do you want zoom? The page itself. The code I got it from slides.com a free presentation application and that's the source code for the slide but because my audience will be on mobile, they will need to zoom in and the presentation just doesn't zoom in so I pulled the code to see if it can be edited to accommodate zoom functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your expected behaviour, you can use simple css transform function scale().

In your example, you can use images instead div in my example

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.square:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.image1 {
  background: black;
}

.image2 {
  background: white;
}
  
.image3 {
  background: red;
}

.image4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="square image1"></div>
<div class="square image2"></div>
<div class="square image3"></div>
<div class="square image4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var imagesize = $('img').width();
    
    $('.zoomout').on('click', function(){
        imagesize = imagesize - 5;
        $('img').width(imagesize);
    });
    
    $('.zoomin').on('click', function(){
        imagesize = imagesize + 5;
        $('img').width(imagesize);
    });
```

```css
div {height:150px; width:150px; display:block; overflow:hidden; outline: 2px solid #777777; padding:20px;}
img {width:150px;}
button {font-size:10px; margin:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_bKbC-4AX-6mG9oeROWNuXK4bKwhYloqxKqKSyiBH58lyuV8-Xg"/></div>
<button class="zoomout">Zoom Out</button > <button class="zoomin">Zoom In</button >
```